# Python - Order dictionary into a list of ascending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following sample code:

```
articles = {'article1.txt': {'harry': 3, 'hermione': 2, 'ron': 1},
 'article2.txt': {'dumbledore': 5, 'hermione': 3},
 'article3.txt': {'harry': 5, 'hermione': 5}}
keywords = ['hermione', 'dumbledore']

def recommend_articles(articles, keywords):

    def max_count(key): 
      result = 0 
      for names in articles.keys():
        for name, count in articles[names].items():
          if name in keywords:
            result += count
            print name, count, result
      return result

    article_list = sorted(articles.keys(), key=max_count, reverse = True)
    print article_list
```

And what gets printed from the function is:

```
hermione 2 2
hermione 5 7
dumbledore 5 12
hermione 3 15
hermione 2 2
hermione 5 7
dumbledore 5 12
hermione 3 15
hermione 2 2
hermione 5 7
dumbledore 5 12
hermione 3 15
['article1.txt', 'article3.txt', 'article2.txt']
```

And I don't quite know what's going on. I should be getting:

```
>>>recommended_articles(articles, keywords)
['article2.txt', 'article3.txt', 'article1.txt']
```

But my function consistently returns `['article1.txt', 'article3.txt', 'article2.txt']`, no matter if I change keywords.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @algerbrex Thanks. `count` would've been the dictionary within articles[outerkey]. I've edited my code to loop through the outer keys, but I'm still running into problems even though I've verified that `count` now occurs in `keywords`.

Comment: Well yes, after looking at your code again, there are several more errors I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
articles = {'article1.txt': {'harry': 3, 'hermione': 2, 'ron': 1},
 'article2.txt': {'dumbledore': 5, 'hermione': 3},
 'article3.txt': {'harry': 5, 'hermione': 5}}
keywords = ['hermione', 'dumbledore']

def recommend_articles(articles, keywords):

    def max_count(key): 
      result = 0 
      for name in articles[key].keys():
        if name in keywords:
          result = result + articles[key][name]
      return result

    article_list = sorted(articles.keys(), key=max_count, reverse = True)
    print article_list

print(recommend_articles(articles, keywords))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an info: Articles is in the form of dict of dict. So you will always get unordered outputs. Try to use ordered dict for articles